# NextJS 13 + sendGrid

Tags: sendgrid, next.js13

I am currently trying the new nextjs13 experiemental appDir, in doing so I trying to get sendGrid working, on previous versions of nextjs I had a sendMail.ts in the api folder and would make fetch requests to it inorder to send out the email.

I trying to get a similar setup working with nextJS 13 with no luck, any idea on how I can get it working?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working sample and the error log?

Comment: can you share code how you are using it from app directory?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what you did previously you'll need to make a fetch request to your endpoint in the app directory.

Here is my contact component where I'm grabbing the data from form fields in a form and making a POST request on submit. This fetch request is using the url matching the path to a route.ts file in my app directory
`/contact/send` fetches the route defined by `/app/contact/send/route.ts`

```
'use client';

import { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';

export const Contact = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onContactFormSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    const elements = e.currentTarget.elements as unknown as Array<
      HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLButtonElement
    >;

    Array.from(elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.name) return;
      formData[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    await fetch('/contact/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setMessage(res.message);
        setStatus(res.status);
        setDisabled(res.message.length > 0);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className='form space-y-2' onSubmit={onContactFormSubmit}>
        <div className='form-control w-full'>
          <label htmlFor='name' className='label cursor-pointer'>
            <span className='label-text'>Name</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='input input-bordered w-full'
            name='name'
            id='name'
            required
            disabled={disabled}
          />
        </div>

        <div className='form-control w-full'>
          <label htmlFor='email' className='label cursor-pointer'>
            <span className='label-text'>Email</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type='email'
            className='input input-bordered w-full'
            name='email'
            id='email'
            required
            disabled={disabled}
          />
        </div>

        <div className='form-control w-full'>
          <label htmlFor='message' className='label cursor-pointer'>
            <span className='label-text'>Message</span>
          </label>
          <textarea
            rows={3}
            className='textarea textarea-bordered w-full'
            name='message'
            id='message'
            required
            disabled={disabled}></textarea>
        </div>

        <button
          type='submit'
          className={`btn btn-block !mt-4 ${
            disabled ? 'btn-disabled' : 'btn-primary'
          }`}
          disabled={disabled}>
          Send Message
        </button>
      </form>
      {message.length > 0 ? (
        <div
          className={`alert shadow-lg mt-4 ${
            status === 'success' ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-error'
          }`}>
          <span>{message}</span>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In `/app/contact/page.tsx` I output my contact form.

```
import { Metadata, NextPage } from 'next/types';
import Contact from '../../components/Contact';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Contact Me',
};

const ContactPage: NextPage = () => {
  return <Contact />;
};

export default ContactPage;
```

My `/app/contact/send/route.ts` file looks like this

```
import mail from '@sendgrid/mail';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

// Create an api key in sendgrid and store someplace safe
mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY || '');

type ResponseData = {
  status?: string;
  message?: string;
};

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  let response: ResponseData = {};
  const body = await request.json();
  // I know the formData I sent in my request has name, email, and message fields so I'm just manually grabbing them to format a message
  const message = `
    Name: ${body.name}\r\n
    Email: ${body.email}\r\n
    Message: ${body.message}
  `;
  const data = {
    to: 'user.email@example.org',
    from: 'hello@example.org',
    subject: 'Contact Message via Sendgrid',
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>'),
  };

  // Send the data and create a response object. I'm using status and message to display a success or fail notification in the UI
  await mail
    .send(data)
    .then(() => {
      response = {
        status: 'success',
        message: "Your message was sent. I'll be in contact shortly.",
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response = {
        status: 'error',
        message: `Message failed to send with error, ${error}`,
      };
    });

  return NextResponse.json(response);
}
```